# Running MSIEXEC in a NSIS script with installer switches

Tags: installation, nsis, windows-installer

I'm trying to build an NSIS installer and package it with necessary drivers (MSI files from the vendor). Eventually, I'd like to install these drivers silently in the backgroud. However, I cannot seem to get it working properly.

In my NSIS script, I have the following:

`ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Flash.msi INSTALLDIR="$INSTDIR\Drivers\Flash""'`

It seems to execute; if I remove the `INSTALLDIR` switch from the above snippet, it'll run the driver installation as expected. But when I leave it in, I'm instead greeted by the following window

[image]

However, running the following directly in Powershell does exactly what I want, sets the install directory appropriately, as expected:

`.\Flash.msi INSTALLDIR=".\Drivers\Flash\"`

I'm guessing it's a silly quotation-mark mismatch somewhere, but I've tried so many already and I get the same results.

Comment: [I guess you have seen this](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers)? Just slightly different from your current command.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Yeah, I saw it. Where's the "slightly" different part? It seems very different to me, but nowhere do I see a way to pass in the installation directory like I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your doublequote for the .msi path is closed too late.

Use

```
ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Flash.msi" INSTALLDIR="$INSTDIR\Drivers\Flash"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following:

```
ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Flash.msi INSTALLDIR=$\"$INSTDIR\Drivers\Flash$\""'
```

or

```
ExecWait 'msiexec /i "$INSTDIR\Flash.msi INSTALLDIR=$\"$\"$INSTDIR\Drivers\Flash$\"$\""'
```

Reference: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html and take a look at the Strings section under 4.1 Script File Format.

Updated with extra escaped quotes.

Comment: Escaping quotes and hoping for success is not the best way to solve something.