# How to go from .msi installer to electron-builder (nsis)

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, electron, electron-builder

I currently have an application out in the field that was distributed as a .msi installer (Built with [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)). I've just finished porting this application over to Electron to take advantage of all of the latest and greatest features including using Electron Builder and Auto Updates.

Any wix/msi gurus know the best way I could uninstall the old msi and run the new installer? The solutions I have found involve searching through the Windows Registry to find the msi UUID then using msiexec.

Is it possible to just create a new version of the .msi that cleans up everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand correctly you want to migrate from MSI to NSIS format?
>   There is an article on this here:
>   https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Uninstalling_a_previous_MSI.

---

I would suggest, however, that you find the **product code** for the MSI and invoke **`msiexec.exe`** with the product code and your own uninstall string (not the one gotten from the registry as shown in the above documentation). This way you can add a few constructs to prevent **spontaneous reboot** and to **enforce proper silent running**. This approach is described below.

---

***Uninstall MSI***: You can uninstall the previous MSI version by running an uninstall command in any number of ways: [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933).

***Find Product Code***: You can find the product GUID of the MSI as follows: [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569)

***Command Line***: Combining approach 3.5 from first link above and the product code found using the information in the second link, you can use a command line like this to invoke from your NSIS installer:

```
msiexec.exe /x {11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111X} /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
```

***Quick Parameter Explanation***:

```
/X = run uninstall sequence
{11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111X} = product guid of app to uninstall
/QN = run completely silently
/L*V "C:\msilog.log"= verbose logging at path specified
REBOOT=ReallySuppress = prevent unexpected reboot of computer
```

***ExecWait***: NSIS requires its own peculiar command format: [Running MSIEXEC in a NSIS script with installer switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51445588/running-msiexec-in-a-nsis-script-with-installer-switches). Haven't tested this yet, but a suggestion:

```
StrCpy $R0 "{11111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111X}";  the MSI's ProductID of my package
ExecWait '"msiexec.exe" /x $R0 /QN REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
```

Check here for fine-tuning the command line: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Uninstalling_a_previous_MSI.

---

***Links***:

- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Uninstalling_a_previous_MSI
- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Auto-uninstall_old_before_installing_new
- [How do I require user to uninstall previous version with NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719631/how-do-i-require-user-to-uninstall-previous-version-with-nsis)
- https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Removing_MSI_packages_with_MSI_related_functions

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. You found a lot more information than I was able to.

Comment: Great that it worked, did you have to make any tweaks to the **`ExecWait`**? I will update the answer "inline" if so. Apologies for the "information overload" - it always happens when trying to make an answer "re-usable".

Comment: The `ExecWait` command worked perfectly. I ended up using `Exec` in order to let the installation finish without needing to wait for the old application to be uninstalled. Thanks again, this was a perfect answer.